# Load a native java serialized payload and write it in the format of byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays, deserialization

I am trying to load a native java serialized payload and write it in the following format(byte arrays):

```
<void index="0"><byte>-87</byte></void>
```

I have to following java script that could help me accomplish this task:

```
File f = new File("/home/john/test/payload.ser");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
String serialized_base = " <void index=\"%d\"><byte>%s</byte></void> \n";

        StringBuilder serialized = new StringBuilder();

        int count = 0;
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        for (int i = 0; i < dis.available(); i++){
          count++;
          serialized.append(String.format(serialized_base, i, dis.readByte()));

        }
```

Unfortunately, when I try to compile the following java script with 'javac test.java' I get the following output:

```
http://test.java:1 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
File f = new File("/home/john/test/payload.ser");
^
http://test.java:2 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
        ^
http://test.java:3 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ^
http://test.java:4 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
String serialized_base = " <void index=\"%d\"><byte>%s</byte></void> \n";
^
http://test.java:6 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
        StringBuilder serialized = new StringBuilder();
        ^
http://test.java:8 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
        int count = 0;
        ^
http://test.java:9 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        ^
http://test.java:10 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
        for (int i = 0; i < dis.available(); i++){
        ^
http://test.java:10 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
        for (int i = 0; i < dis.available(); i++){
                        ^
http://test.java:10 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
        for (int i = 0; i < dis.available(); i++){
                                             ^
http://test.java:12 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
          serialized.append(String.format(serialized_base, i, dis.readByte()));
          ^
http://test.java:14 : error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
12 errors
```

I am opened to any suggestions that would let me load a native java serialized payload and write it in the required format.

Any help is very appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Based on the line numbers, it looks like you tried to dump Java statements directly in a file instead of including them in a class and method.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make my goal possible? I have been on this since yesterday with no success.

Comment: You need to look at an introductory tutorial on how to write a Java main class.